# Trigger con NULL DATE que no coincide al hacer una búsqueda

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, trigger

Tengo este Trigger y si grabo el campo Caducidad en VB.NET sin ncad se me graba NULO. Hasta aquí todo correcto, pero cuando lo comparo con el Trigger no me encuentra el nulo. Cada vez que inserto busco la caducidad pero como está en nulo no la encuentra y me añade un registro en lugar de hacer el update. ¿Podríais ayudarme?

```
USE [MBGestioDB001]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Stock_Almacen]    Script Date: 05/11/2016 10:46:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER  trigger [dbo].[Stock_Almacen]
   on [dbo].[Linpediv]
   for Insert<br>
   as 
   DECLARE @CREFERENCIA VARCHAR(50), @CALMACEN INT, @Unitats as float, @CLOT AS VARCHAR(50), @CADUCITAT AS DATE
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON<br>
   Select @CREFERENCIA = [IDREFERENCIA] from inserted 
   Select @UNITATS = ISNULL([UNITATSentrada],0)-ISNULL([UNITATS],0) from inserted 
   SELECT @CALMACEN= [IDALMACEN] FROM INSERTED
   SELECT @CLOT= ISNULL([LOT],'') FROM INSERTED
   SELECT @CADUCITAT= [CADUCITAT] FROM INSERTED<br>
   IF not EXISTS (SELECT IDREFERENCIA,IDALMACEN,LOTE,ISNULL(CADUCIDAD,null) FROM Articles_Almacen WHERE IDREFERENCIA=@CREFERENCIA AND IDALMACEN=@CALMACEN AND LOTE=@CLOT AND CADUCIDAD=@CADUCITAT)
      INSERT INTO ARTICLES_ALMACEN (IDReferencia, STOCK, IDAlmacen, LOTE,CADUCIDAD) VALUES (@CREFERENCIA,@UNITATS,@CALMACEN,@CLOT,@CADUCITAT)
   ELSE
      UPDATE ARTICLES_ALMACEN SET STOCK=STOCK + @UNITATS WHERE IDREFERENCIA=@CREFERENCIA AND IDALMACEN=@CALMACEN AND LOTE=@CLOT AND CADUCIDAD=@CADUCITAT
```

Answer (score 1):

El valor `null` es especial, y no puedes compararla con los métodos usuales.

A modo de ejemplo, si ejecutas:

```
select 1 where null = null;
```

...verás que no te devuelve ningún registro, por mas raro que parezca. Eso es porque para comparar el valor `null` en SQL, tienes que usar el operador `IS`. Si usas el operador `=`, siempre te devolverá `false`.

Por ejemplo:

```
select 1 where null is null;
```

...ahora sí devuelve un registro.

De modo que si sabes que el campo `CADUCIDAD` y la variable `@CADUCITAT` pueden llevar el valor `null`, debes modificar la condión en tu `select` de esta manera:

```
IF not EXISTS (
  SELECT IDREFERENCIA,IDALMACEN,LOTE,ISNULL(CADUCIDAD,null) 
    FROM Articles_Almacen 
   WHERE IDREFERENCIA=@CREFERENCIA 
     AND IDALMACEN=@CALMACEN 
     AND LOTE=@CLOT 
     AND (CADUCIDAD=@CADUCITAT or (CADUCIDAD is null and @CADUCITAT is null)) -- aquí va el cambio, cuidado con las paréntesis
)
```

**Notas adicionales**

La expresión:

```
ISNULL(CADUCIDAD,null)
```

...no tiene sentido. Con esa expresión, estás diciendo que si `CADUCIDAD` es `null`, que lo reemplazes con `null`. En otras palabras, no cambia nada. Puedes quitar el `ISNULL`.

Otro punto, es en cuanto al `EXISTS` o `NO EXISTS`. Este operador solo verifica si la sub consulta devuelve algún registro o no. De modo que no importa cuales columnas definas en tu `select`, de todas maneras no importan.

Por eso, los siguientes ejemplos son todos equivalentes:

```
IF not EXISTS (
  SELECT IDREFERENCIA,IDALMACEN,LOTE,ISNULL(CADUCIDAD,null) 
    FROM Articles_Almacen 
    -- etc...
)

IF not EXISTS (
  SELECT *
    FROM Articles_Almacen 
    -- etc...
)

IF not EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
    FROM Articles_Almacen 
    -- etc...
)

IF not EXISTS (
  SELECT null
    FROM Articles_Almacen 
    -- etc...
)
```

Muchos les gusta usar `select 1`, a mí me gusta `select null`. Al final no importa cual escojas, SQL Server entiende que el `select` en sí no tiene importancia y optimisa la consulta en consecuencia. De modo que no hay ninguna diferencia en resultado ni rendimiento entre las 4 opciones.

Comment: Muchisimaz gracias

Answer (score 1):

### NULL en el estándar SQL

El valor **`NULL`** no es simplemente un valor más que puede tener un campo. NULL significa algo así como **valor desconocido**, o **ausencia de valor**. Por tanto, los operadores funcionan de manera diferente a lo que, si no conoces del tema, podrías esperar al encontrar valores NULL.

Por ejemplo, el operador de comparación de igualdad `=`, veamoslo así:

```
1 = 1  => Verdadero
1 = 2  => Falso
1 = null => null (leelo como ¿es uno igual a un valor desconocido?, 
                  y verás que la respuesta es igualmente desconocida.)
null = null => null (¿es desconocido igual a desconocido?)
```

de manera similar funcionan otros operadores de comparación:

```
1 <> 2 => Verdadero
1 <> 1 => Falso
1 <> null => null (¿es uno distinto de un valor desconocido?)
null != null => null (¿es un valor desconocido distinto de otro valor desconocido?)
1 > 0 => Verdadero
1 > 2 => Falso
1 > null => null (de igual manera, ¿es uno mayor que un valor desconocido?,
                  el resultado es igualmente desconocido).
null > null => null (¿es desconocido mayor que desconocido?)
```

También las operaciones aritméticas, de fechas o de manipulación de cadenas, por ejemplo

```
1 + 1 => 2
1 + null => null (uno mas valor desconocido => valor desconocido)

'a' + 'b' => 'ab' (1)
'a' + null => null

dateadd(day, 30, '20100101') => '20100131'
dateadd(day, null, '20100101') => null
```

(1) Hablamos de SQL Server y la concatenación se hace con el operador `+`, lo dicho es válido para el operador || del estándar y la mayoría de los motores.

## Lógica de 3 estados

SQL no utiliza una lógica booleana de 2 estados, como la que hemos aprendido todos en nuestros primeros pasos en la programación. Dada la existencia del valor **`NULL`**, el estándar SQL maneja las siguientes tablas de verdad para las operaciones lógicas.

```
----------------------------------------------
|    A   |    B   | A and B | A or B | not A | 
----------------------------------------------
|  True  |  True  |  True   |  True  | False |
|  True  |  False |  False  |  True  |       |
|  True  |  NULL  |  NULL   |  True  |       |
|  False |  True  |  False  |  True  | True  |
|  False |  False |  False  |  False |       |
|  False |  NULL  |  False  |  NULL  |       |
|  NULL  |  True  |  NULL   |  True  | NULL  |
|  NULL  |  False |  False  |  NULL  |       |
|  NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL   |  NULL  |       |
----------------------------------------------
```

## SQL Server y los NULL

En mi experiencia, SQL Server es uno de los motores de base de datos que menos cumple con el estándar (para algunos es bueno para otros no tanto). Dentro de esto, SQL Server tradicionalmente daba otro tratamiento a los valores NULL y para manetener la compatibilidad, existe el parámetro [`ansi_nulls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188048.aspx).

Este se puede establecer con la instrucción **`set ansi_nulls on/off`**

Lo primero es decir que **no se recomienda su uso** para desarrollos nuevos, si lo menciono aquí es porque puedes topartelo en un desarrollo existente. Lo dice la misma documentación:

> En una versión futura de SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS siempre se establecerá en ON y cualquier aplicación que establezca de forma explícita la opción en OFF generará un error. Evite utilizar esta característica en nuevos trabajos de desarrollo y tenga previsto modificar las aplicaciones que actualmente la utilizan.

Cuando ansi_nulls está en OFF, el tratamiendo del valor NULL es como si fuese otro valor cualquiera en la columna, la documentación inicia diciendo:

> Cuando SET ANSI_NULLS se establece en OFF, los operadores de comparación Es igual a (=) y No es igual a (<>) no siguen el estándar ISO. Una instrucción SELECT que utilice WHERE column_name = NULL devuelve las filas que tienen valores NULL en column_name. Una instrucción SELECT que utilice WHERE column_name <> NULL devuelve las filas que tienen valores no NULL en la columna. Además, una instrucción SELECT que utilice WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value devuelve todas las filas que no son XYZ_value y que no son NULL.

Para más información, visita [este enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188048.aspx).